# Bluebird promisifyAll instead of individual promisifying functions

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I have certain service functions in the format to callback error and response, so that it can be successfully promisified.

Example:
service.js

```
functionA(callback) {
...
callback(error, response);
}
functionB(callback) {
...
callback(error, response);
}
module.exports.functionA = functionA;
module.exports.functionB = functionB;
```

From a controller, I successfully promisified using

```
const functionA = Promise.promisify(service.functionA);
const functionB = Promise.promisify(service.functionB);
```

But to optimize the code, I used:

```
const {functionA, functionB} = Promise.promisifyAll(service);
```

which is not working...with error "callback is not a function".
Is it not possible to use Bluebird promisifyAll like that?

Comment: `promisifyAll` creates new methods with a suffixed method name. Your destructuring gets the original methods.

Comment: Sorry @Bergi, I din get you. Is it not possible to map those functions the way I did?

Comment: No, it is not possibly. You'd need to do `const {functionAAsync, functionBAsync} = …`, and even that doesn't work as they lost their context.

Comment: Yeah I logged the Promise.promisifyAll(service) to see { functionA: [Function: functionA],
  functionB: [Function: functionB],
  functionAAsync: [Function],
  functionBAsync: [Function] }

Comment: Btw, is that service written by you?

Comment: @Bergi When I used functionAAsync and functionBAsync mapping, got it working. Why do you say "and even that doesn't work as they lost their context."?? Is it wrong?
Yes the service is mine.

Comment: I would've guessed that you got a "cannot call .functionA(…) on undefined" error when invoking `functionAAsync(…)`, but maybe this is fixed now in Bluebird.

Comment: If you've written the service yourself, then you should make it `return` promises in the first place, instead taking callbacks and needing to be promisified. Instead, promisify the asynchronous APIs that the service is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Bluebird doc](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html), used the suffix in call:

```
const {functionAAsync, functionBAsync} = Promise.promisifyAll(service);
```

Working fine.